# Political leanings on the county level, or state level?

Tags: government, politics

I've compiled some covid data, and I think adding some political leaning data might make it a little spicy. I've seen some maps of political leaning for counties, but I cant find a source. I'm looking for a data set that has counties (or states, preferably counties) that show their political leanings. Hopefully in a simple format, like +4 Democrat or +4 Republican.

Comment: do you mean polling data, or election results? polling data may not be complete, since some counties are not-so-interesting for the election.

Comment: Election results, should have mentioned that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

538 has a pretty cool election forecast page:

https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-election-forecast/

you can get a direct download of the polling data: https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/data-webpage-data/datasets/polls.zip

they also have a data page at github that links other CSVs and explains the data model: https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/election-forecasts-2020

[image]